# What would a blind civilization look like?

Tags: society, government

Blind humans basically, though they are more adept in echolocation.
They're also not born blind, they just believe that sight stains our understanding of the world, that it is a curse that must be taken away. This happens when they've turned 5 years old.

Comment: this is hugely opinion based. If you give a look around you see that human civilizations look very different from each other. Why would adding the blind flavor make it any difference?

Comment: Yes, somewhat opinion based, but one thing we do know for certain...   "in the land of the blind, the one-eyed man is king."   Which implies a patriarchal monarchy.  That limits the scope quite a bit.   Also, since only children under 5 have eyes to see, the civilization would "look" pretty simple... because only very young eyes would be involved in the "looking".

Comment: Has Mister Onion read the H.G. Wells story, "The Country of the Blind"? He should read that & think about what differences he would make from Wells

Comment: @JimBaerg Thanks for the recommendation!